# How to add export as csv option in Active Admin for custom generated page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have a custom generated page which list database records. For eg: lets assume I list all the users.

How can I add download as csv option to this page.

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "My Page" do
  menu :label => "My Page"

  content do
    @user = User.all
    div do
      # view page for listing users
      render '/admin/dashboard/my_users_list/', { :user => @user } 
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

ActiveAdmin includes CSV formats for the resources already, see [Customizing the CSV format](http://activeadmin.info/docs/4-csv-format.html)

> Active Admin provides CSV file downloads on the index screen for each Resource. By default it will render a CSV file with all the content columns of your registered model.

Which means, you can just construct a link to that already-existing route in your custom page

```
link_to "User CSV", admin_users_path( :format => :csv )
```

Comment: Actually its returning all the content columns of your registered model. I want particular months data. How to fetch CSV for this ?

Comment: @SaravanaKumAr ActiveAdmin provides documentation on how to customize your CSV. I referenced that in my answer, see "Customizing the CSV Format".